# String.format escape curly braces

Tags: apex, string, escape

Is there a way to escape curly braces within String.format?

E.g. if I want to get the following output:

> {777}

I'd expected {{ would do the job but this code throws an exception:

> String.format('{{{0}}}', new String[] { String.valueOf(777) });
>
> can't parse argument number: {{0}}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how this is done

```
System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,String.format('\'{\'{0}\'}\'', 
     new String[] { String.valueOf(777) }));
```

produces `{777}`

SFDC `String.format` (also used by VF `apex:outputtext`) uses the Java `MessageFormat` class. And braces are escaped by enclosing in single quotes, which in apex must also be escaped by backslash.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187093/can-i-escape-braces-in-a-java-messageformat

Answer (score 0):

> Actually what String.format method do is it finds a number within a
>   combination of two braces. In your case the orginal string is {{{0}}}
>   and so it finds "{{0}}" this string within first combination of braces
>   and so its trying to parse it in a number and thats why showing a
>   parsing error coz "{{0}}" cannot be converted in number.

You can use any other string methods like substitute etc. to do the same.

Comment: In c# that's what it would look like and it would work: string.Format("{{{0}}}", someString) would result in {someStringValue}. I'm trying to do the same in Apex.

Comment: Yes I understood your point, but may be the string class & its method implementation is different as compared to the string class in C#, that could be a reason.

Comment: But what if there's a way to escape them in Apex as well? :)